# Not start play! application in Microsoft Azure on CentOS

Tags: azure, playframework, centos

I created a virtual machine CentOS.
Created end-point in the control panel on port 80 and 443. In CentOS added rules to iptables:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Thu Aug  9 18:07:49 2012
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [142:12032]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [146:18544]
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Aug  9 18:07:49 2012
```

Run the application:

```
CompilerOracle: exclude jregex/Pretokenizer.next
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000
18:07:05,799 INFO  ~ Starting /srv/play-1.2.5/localevent
18:07:05,808 INFO  ~ Module .svn is ignored, name starts with a dot
18:07:06,820 WARN  ~ You're running Play! in DEV mode
18:07:06,975 INFO  ~ Listening for HTTP at /127.0.0.1:80 (Waiting a first request to start) ...
```

I went to the address: *.сloudapp.net

But the application does not start. In what may be the reason?

### #update1

SELinux is disabled. Version of CentOS - 6.2

### #update2

For the test was installed Apache. Home Apache displayed.
Added proxy from 80 to 9000 port in httpd.conf. Play was launched at the 9000 port.
Apache returns a 503 error. Wget 127.0.0.1:9000 gets everything right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looked logs Apache:

```
[error] (13) Permission denied: proxy: HTTP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:9000 (127.0.0.1) failed
[error] ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (127.0.0.1)
```

Solution:

```
setsebool httpd_can_network_connect 1
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you have to add an endpoint to your Azure virtual machine in order to allow to connect to the 80 TCP port.

For instance, see this [doc](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tconte/archive/2012/06/08/running-redis-on-a-centos-linux-vm-in-windows-azure.aspx), under the "Expose Redis to the outside" section, by setting your private and public ports to 80.

Comment: I think Anton already did that. ("Created end-point in the control panel on port 80 and 443.")